# Why would I ever use a class over an attribute in HTML and CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, attributes

I'm creating a web app and need to decide on a consistent way to style my elements. I noticed that a lot of help online uses classes but I have generally used attributes (like the query selector [my-attr]) to style multiple elements, since I don't have to work with classList and can remove and set attributes very easily.

Using no external libraries, why would people use classes to style their elements over attributes? It seems like attributes can do everything classes can do but better, since you can also assign values to the attributes as well. I also haven't seen any discussion on performance differences anywhere, making me believe that attributes should be more appreciated than they are in tutorials on styling pages.

Any thoughts on instances where classes could do a better job than attributes at something would be greatly appreciated, even if the arguments are subjective and come down to some sort of preference!

Thanks!

Again, this is for vanilla javascript, HTML, and CSS. I understand that libraries like jQuery may make it easier to use classes, but I don't plan on using any libraries.

Comment: because classes are created for styling purpose and attribute for adding data like title, target, etc ... but CSS is strong enough and allow you to use attribute selector. And if you want to have a common style, you will add the same attribute everywhere? i don't think it's a good idea

Comment: Please clarify: how do you _use[d] attributes (like the query selector [my-attr]) to style multiple elements_?

Comment: I can make a div with an attribute like <div my-style></div> and style it in a stylesheet with [my-style] { background-color: red; } for example. I can do the same thing with classes but am wondering why classes are often preferred over attributes for this purpose

Comment: @Bradass - got it...you know, a lot of people (in the USA) drive pickup trucks and never ever haul a load in the back. Same thing here. There is no reason a person must drive a sedan - they can drive a pickup if they choose. You can use attributes if you choose, but it may not be the best choice based upon the standards/specs we all develop too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's more consistent, is the end-all be all, truthfully. If you'd rather use attributes, go for it. However it makes it just *that* much more difficult for anyone who has to help you out later. CSS classes are designed for grouped selection and application of common styles. CSS just *happens* to also be able to select attributes as well, because it does make sense in some edge cases.

Generally, attributes should be reserved for anything non-style related that adds a value for a different use, be it screen-readers or variable containers for JavaScript, such as `data-id="34"` may let you make an asynchronous request with the ID parameter.

Consider this example, it's got some simple "class" based buttons:

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.primary {
  background: currentColor;
}

.primary span {
  color: #fff;
}

.blue {
  color: #0095ee;
}

.red {
  color: #ee3300
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button red">Red Button</a>
<a href="#" class="button red primary"><span>Red Button</span></a>
<br />
<a href="#" class="button blue">Blue Button</a>
<a href="#" class="button blue primary"><span>Blue Button</span></a>
```

To replicate something like this with attributes, we'll be doing something like this with some obnoxious and rather arbitrary attribute names. Doing this I actually messed up because I used the wrong attribute name and value pair in one case.

```css
[type="button"] {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

[status="primary"] {
  background: currentColor;
}

[status="primary"]  span {
  color: #fff;
}

[color="blue"] {
  color: #0095ee;
}

[color="red"] {
  color: #ee3300
}
```

```html
<a href="#" type="button" color="red">Red Button</a>
<a href="#" type="button" color="red" status="primary"><span>Red Button</span></a>
<br />
<a href="#" type="button" color="blue">Blue Button</a>
<a href="#" type="button" color="blue" status="primary"><span>Blue Button</span></a>
```

Does it not make more semantic sense to keep all your stylistic and group target attributes inside the `class` attribute? I mean, that's what it was designed for. I suppose you could drop the parameter value and just use parameter names, but you're really defeating the purpose of attributes, considering `class` is a [Global Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) in and of itself.

Here's a JavaScript example as well:

```js
let classes = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
for( i = 0, n = classes.length; i < n; ++i ){
  classes[i].style.background = 'red';
}

let attrs = document.querySelectorAll('[button]');
for( i = 0, n = attrs.length; i < n; ++i ){
  attrs[i].style.background = 'blue';
}
```

```css
a { 
 padding: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 4px;
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" button>Attr 1</a>
<a href="#" button>Attr 2</a>
<a href="#" button>Attr 3</a>
<br />
<a href="#" class="button">Class 1</a>
<a href="#" class="button">Class 2</a>
<a href="#" class="button">Class 3</a>
```

Putting aside the fact that JS has immense integration with class (and id) based functions for selectors, you **have** to use `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` for the attribute buttons.

While not inherently a bad thing, (honestly I prefer `querySelector` over `getElement(s)By…` in general), but when you look at it, `querySelectorAll('[button]')` just does not read well, almost like I'm targeting a `<button>` element. Semantically it makes it harder to read than:

`getElementsByClassName('button')` - Clearly getting all elements that have a button class, or even

`querySelectorAll('.button')` - Since the `.` is universally understood as the "class" selector, and everyone working with HTML, CSS, and JS learns that on literally day 1 of any web development program/tutorial. So you're throwing a bit of a wrench into the project by removing such a fundamental piece of it.

I'm sure you've heard the phrase "Just because you can, doesn't mean you should." - I think that applies perfectly here. I mean, we actually *used* to use things like `<font color="red">Red</font>` and we moved away from it because it made more sense to group styles in a single Global Attribute. There's nothing stopping you, but I think it's asking for more trouble than it's worth to drop classes for arbitrary parameter names, not to mention if you have an issue and post your code for help, the first response will *always* be "Why are you doing that, what preprocessor are you using?"

Comment: Other reasons to prefer `querySelectorAll` The getElementsBy* methods return HTMLCollection. qSA returns a static NodeList - unlike an HTMLCollection, it can be iterated over directly, and it won't change while it's being iterated over.

Comment: I see. I've only worked on smaller projects and usually alone which is why attributes were not too cumbersome, but this makes a lot more sense for big and small projects alike, and when other people are involved. Especially the ability to keep all styles under one global attribute. Thanks for the detailed response!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just the functional probl, if you want to give style u should use class, but if you want to modify u can use query selector cause it will not added an inline style on your html and you can minify the script.